# when pressed 'Click' button on chrome extension pop-up, form should be filled

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to develop a chrome extension wherein there is a 'Click' button on popup and when I press that click button, it should fill the registration form on the webpage.

I am new to coding, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend going through Google's chrome extension tutorial to get an understanding of the different components you will need to use.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

You will need to create a popup html page and popup script. Then have a content script to directly interact with the webpage.